# In Google cloud messaging for android

Tags: java, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, sencha-touch

In my android application, i need to do push notification so, i searched for that and i found Google Cloud Messaging at android guide, [step by step procedure](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html).

In Writing the Android Application

Step 3: Write the my_app_package.GCMIntentService class

i need to create GCMIntentService class extended from GCMBaseIntentService and i need to implement abstract methods(onRegistered,onUnregistered,etc) in GCMBaseIntentService and in onRegistered method i should send the regid to your server so it can use it to send messages to device.

I got Cordova GCM Push Notifications Plugin for Android example from [here](https://github.com/marknutter/GCM-Cordova)

1) there i saw they implemented GCMIntentService class (at src/com/cordova2/gcm), in that class, see onRegistered method, after getting json i don't know why they are calling GCMPlugin.sendJavascript( json ) in line 39?.

2) how to develop client and server for push notification using Google cloud messaging

Comment: very nice tutorial here http://tech-papers.org/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-for-android-and-push-notifications-2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check following link for Android Push notification With server code=
    http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: Sure I will avoid in next answers